# which part of the d3 initialization should be put into meteor autorun to make the charts reactive?

Tags: meteor, d3.js

Just started learning meteor and d3 / crossfilter charting libraries.
Picked up some example code off the Web, and have it working in my local app.
I do have an empty this.autorun() function in my meteor client code, but have no idea what part of the lengthy d3 initialization and composition routine should be put into autorun, in order for these charts to react to the data changes.
I have tried to just put the Flights.find().fetch() inside the autorun, but in that case, the page never seem to finish loading.
Here is my entire meteor code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {


  Template.dashboard.helpers({

  });

  Template.dashboard.events({

  });

    Template.dashboard.rendered = function(){

        var flights = Flights.find().fetch();
        if (!flights.length) return;
        var crossData = crossfilter(flights);

       // d3.csv(data, function(error, flights) {

            // Various formatters.
            var formatNumber = d3.format(",d"),
                formatChange = d3.format("+,d"),
                formatDate = d3.time.format("%B %d, %Y"),
                formatTime = d3.time.format("%I:%M %p");

            // A nest operator, for grouping the flight list.
            var nestByDate = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) { return d3.time.day(d.date); });

            // A little coercion, since the CSV is untyped.
            flights.forEach(function(d, i) {
                d.index = i;
                d.date = parseDate(d.date);
                d.delay = +d.delay;
                d.distance = +d.distance;
            });

            // Create the crossfilter for the relevant dimensions and groups.
            var flight = crossfilter(flights),
                all = flight.groupAll(),
                date = flight.dimension(function(d) { return d.date; }),
                dates = date.group(d3.time.day),
                hour = flight.dimension(function(d) { return d.date.getHours() + d.date.getMinutes() / 60; }),
                hours = hour.group(Math.floor),
                delay = flight.dimension(function(d) { return Math.max(-60, Math.min(149, d.delay)); }),
                delays = delay.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / 10) * 10; }),
                distance = flight.dimension(function(d) { return Math.min(1999, d.distance); }),
                distances = distance.group(function(d) { return Math.floor(d / 50) * 50; });

            var charts = [

                barChart()
                    .dimension(hour)
                    .group(hours)
                    .x(d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, 24])
                        .rangeRound([0, 10 * 24])),

                barChart()
                    .dimension(delay)
                    .group(delays)
                    .x(d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([-60, 150])
                        .rangeRound([0, 10 * 21])),

                barChart()
                    .dimension(distance)
                    .group(distances)
                    .x(d3.scale.linear()
                        .domain([0, 2000])
                        .rangeRound([0, 10 * 40])),

                barChart()
                    .dimension(date)
                    .group(dates)
                    .round(d3.time.day.round)
                    .x(d3.time.scale()
                        .domain([new Date(2001, 0, 1), new Date(2001, 3, 1)])
                        .rangeRound([0, 10 * 90]))
                    .filter([new Date(2001, 1, 1), new Date(2001, 2, 1)])

            ];

            // Given our array of charts, which we assume are in the same order as the
            // .chart elements in the DOM, bind the charts to the DOM and render them.
            // We also listen to the chart's brush events to update the display.
            var chart = d3.selectAll(".chart")
                .data(charts)
                .each(function(chart) { chart.on("brush", renderAll).on("brushend", renderAll); });

            // Render the initial lists.
            var list = d3.selectAll(".list")
                .data([flightList]);

            // Render the total.
            d3.selectAll("#total")
                .text(formatNumber(flight.size()));

            renderAll();

            // Renders the specified chart or list.
            function render(method) {
                d3.select(this).call(method);
            }

            // Whenever the brush moves, re-rendering everything.
            function renderAll() {
                chart.each(render);
                list.each(render);
                d3.select("#active").text(formatNumber(all.value()));
            }

            // Like d3.time.format, but faster.
            function parseDate(d) {
                return new Date(2001,
                    d.substring(0, 2) - 1,
                    d.substring(2, 4),
                    d.substring(4, 6),
                    d.substring(6, 8));
            }

            window.filter = function(filters) {
                filters.forEach(function(d, i) { charts[i].filter(d); });
                renderAll();
            };

            window.reset = function(i) {
                charts[i].filter(null);
                renderAll();
            };

            function flightList(div) {
                var flightsByDate = nestByDate.entries(date.top(40));

                div.each(function() {
                    var date = d3.select(this).selectAll(".date")
                        .data(flightsByDate, function(d) { return d.key; });

                    date.enter().append("div")
                        .attr("class", "date")
                        .append("div")
                        .attr("class", "day")
                        .text(function(d) { return formatDate(d.values[0].date); });

                    date.exit().remove();

                    var flight = date.order().selectAll(".flight")
                        .data(function(d) { return d.values; }, function(d) { return d.index; });

                    var flightEnter = flight.enter().append("div")
                        .attr("class", "flight");

                    flightEnter.append("div")
                        .attr("class", "time")
                        .text(function(d) { return formatTime(d.date); });

                    flightEnter.append("div")
                        .attr("class", "origin")
                        .text(function(d) { return d.origin; });

                    flightEnter.append("div")
                        .attr("class", "destination")
                        .text(function(d) { return d.destination; });

                    flightEnter.append("div")
                        .attr("class", "distance")
                        .text(function(d) { return formatNumber(d.distance) + " mi."; });

                    flightEnter.append("div")
                        .attr("class", "delay")
                        .classed("early", function(d) { return d.delay < 0; })
                        .text(function(d) { return formatChange(d.delay) + " min."; });

                    flight.exit().remove();

                    flight.order();
                });
            }

            function barChart() {
                if (!barChart.id) barChart.id = 0;

                var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20, left: 10},
                    x,
                    y = d3.scale.linear().range([100, 0]),
                    id = barChart.id++,
                    axis = d3.svg.axis().orient("bottom"),
                    brush = d3.svg.brush(),
                    brushDirty,
                    dimension,
                    group,
                    round;

                function chart(div) {
                    var width = x.range()[1],
                        height = y.range()[0];

                    y.domain([0, group.top(1)[0].value]);

                    div.each(function() {
                        var div = d3.select(this),
                            g = div.select("g");

                        // Create the skeletal chart.
                        if (g.empty()) {
                            div.select(".title").append("a")
                                .attr("href", "javascript:reset(" + id + ")")
                                .attr("class", "reset")
                                .text("reset")
                                .style("display", "none");

                            g = div.append("svg")
                                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                                .append("g")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

                            g.append("clipPath")
                                .attr("id", "clip-" + id)
                                .append("rect")
                                .attr("width", width)
                                .attr("height", height);

                            g.selectAll(".bar")
                                .data(["background", "foreground"])
                                .enter().append("path")
                                .attr("class", function(d) { return d + " bar"; })
                                .datum(group.all());

                            g.selectAll(".foreground.bar")
                                .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip-" + id + ")");

                            g.append("g")
                                .attr("class", "axis")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                                .call(axis);

                            // Initialize the brush component with pretty resize handles.
                            var gBrush = g.append("g").attr("class", "brush").call(brush);
                            gBrush.selectAll("rect").attr("height", height);
                            gBrush.selectAll(".resize").append("path").attr("d", resizePath);
                        }

                        // Only redraw the brush if set externally.
                        if (brushDirty) {
                            brushDirty = false;
                            g.selectAll(".brush").call(brush);
                            div.select(".title a").style("display", brush.empty() ? "none" : null);
                            if (brush.empty()) {
                                g.selectAll("#clip-" + id + " rect")
                                    .attr("x", 0)
                                    .attr("width", width);
                            } else {
                                var extent = brush.extent();
                                g.selectAll("#clip-" + id + " rect")
                                    .attr("x", x(extent[0]))
                                    .attr("width", x(extent[1]) - x(extent[0]));
                            }
                        }

                        g.selectAll(".bar").attr("d", barPath);
                    });

                    function barPath(groups) {
                        var path = [],
                            i = -1,
                            n = groups.length,
                            d;
                        while (++i < n) {
                            d = groups[i];
                            path.push("M", x(d.key), ",", height, "V", y(d.value), "h9V", height);
                        }
                        return path.join("");
                    }

                    function resizePath(d) {
                        var e = +(d == "e"),
                            x = e ? 1 : -1,
                            y = height / 3;
                        return "M" + (.5 * x) + "," + y
                            + "A6,6 0 0 " + e + " " + (6.5 * x) + "," + (y + 6)
                            + "V" + (2 * y - 6)
                            + "A6,6 0 0 " + e + " " + (.5 * x) + "," + (2 * y)
                            + "Z"
                            + "M" + (2.5 * x) + "," + (y + 8)
                            + "V" + (2 * y - 8)
                            + "M" + (4.5 * x) + "," + (y + 8)
                            + "V" + (2 * y - 8);
                    }
                }

                brush.on("brushstart.chart", function() {
                    var div = d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
                    div.select(".title a").style("display", null);
                });

                brush.on("brush.chart", function() {
                    var g = d3.select(this.parentNode),
                        extent = brush.extent();
                    if (round) g.select(".brush")
                        .call(brush.extent(extent = extent.map(round)))
                        .selectAll(".resize")
                        .style("display", null);
                    g.select("#clip-" + id + " rect")
                        .attr("x", x(extent[0]))
                        .attr("width", x(extent[1]) - x(extent[0]));
                    dimension.filterRange(extent);
                });

                brush.on("brushend.chart", function() {
                    if (brush.empty()) {
                        var div = d3.select(this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
                        div.select(".title a").style("display", "none");
                        div.select("#clip-" + id + " rect").attr("x", null).attr("width", "100%");
                        dimension.filterAll();
                    }
                });

                chart.margin = function(_) {
                    if (!arguments.length) return margin;
                    margin = _;
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.x = function(_) {
                    if (!arguments.length) return x;
                    x = _;
                    axis.scale(x);
                    brush.x(x);
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.y = function(_) {
                    if (!arguments.length) return y;
                    y = _;
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.dimension = function(_) {
                    if (!arguments.length) return dimension;
                    dimension = _;
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.filter = function(_) {
                    if (_) {
                        brush.extent(_);
                        dimension.filterRange(_);
                    } else {
                        brush.clear();
                        dimension.filterAll();
                    }
                    brushDirty = true;
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.group = function(_) {
                    if (!arguments.length) return group;
                    group = _;
                    return chart;
                };

                chart.round = function(_) {
                    if (!arguments.length) return round;
                    round = _;
                    return chart;
                };

                return d3.rebind(chart, brush, "on");
            }
       // });

        this.autorun(function(){

        })


    }
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {

  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this helps, here is my attempt at reproducing one of the d3 force layout examples with collision detection / custom gravity functions https://gist.github.com/gmlnchv/80dd206440cca39800b8. I'm using [`observe()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe) to react to changes.